# Three js Uncaught TypeError: THREE.OBJLoader is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, three.js

понимаю что ошибка частая, и ругается что я не импортировал OBJLoader, но все решения которые я нашёл импортируют его локально, по пути. То есть он установлен у них на сервере. Я же импортирую Three.js по ссылке:
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.js"></script>`
Как мне достать OBJLoader из ссылки?

Comment: Через импорт ...

Comment: `import {OBJLoader} from './resources/threejs/r132/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';`

Comment: И делать эть надо в модуле иначе импорт не сработает

Comment: @Айболит разве это сработает если Three.js не установлен локально?

Comment: Просто как мне в таком случае получить доступ к модулю?

Comment: Смотрите: https://discoverthreejs.com/book/introduction/get-threejs/

Comment: @Айболит Можете подсказать путь откуда импортировать OBJLoader в таком случае?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130833/discussion-between-artemgh-and-).

Comment: В итоге я просто скачал файл OBJLoader.js к себе на локалку, и пытаюсь импортировать `import {OBJLoader} from './OBJLoader.js';`. И мне выдается ошибка Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './OBJLoader.js' does not provide an export named 'OBJLoader'

Comment: @Айболит из-за чего может быть ошибка?

Comment: У меня щас нету компа рядом, я в командировке...